# Do animations stop css changes after animation completion?

Tags: css

I have an animation upon opening a drawer, which is a bounce up from the bottom then stop at 33 percent height. After the animation, the drawer needs to be draggable. I am creating the draggable functionality by adjusting the height and top of the fixed position drawer.

Problem:

After an animation finishes, the height of the drawer no longer re-renders. The CSS 'height' property does adjust properly, but the new height does not display.

How do I get the height of the drawer to adjust correctly?

I havent tried anything, I dont understand what the underlying problem is.

```css
.spring {
      animation-name: spring-action;
      animation-timing-function: ease;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-delay: 1s;
      animation-direction: normal;
      animation-duration:1.2s;
      transform-origin: bottom;
}

@keyframes spring-action {
  0%   { height: 0%; }
  50%   { height:40%; }
  100%   { height: 33%; }
}
```

I am expecting the height of the drawer to increase upon drag, but the drawer only drags up (top is adjusted and rendered) without adjusting the height.

Comment: put `height: 33%;` on the element and remove `forwards`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `max-height` or `min-height` instead of `height`

```css
.spring {
      animation: spring-action 3s 1 ease forwards;
      transform-origin: bottom;
}

@keyframes spring-action {
  0%   { min-height: 0% ;}
  50%   { min-height:40% ;}
  100%   { min-height: 33% ; }
} 


.spring{
background:#2f0;
width:300px;
}

.container{
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="spring">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, this worked, thank you! I dont understand why this was an issue. 

Why does animation-fill-mode freeze all of the changes to height after the animation finishes?

why does min-height work? It was my impression that min-height only works if the height of the container is larger than the min height value.

Answer (score 0):

`height: auto` this is a default value for each element, Also, the height no inherited. If `height: auto;` the element will automatically adjust its height to allow its content to be displayed correctly.

When you set `height:{n}%` it's `{n}%` of parent element.

The `min-height` and `max-height` properties override the height property.

`min-height` property default value is zero ( 0 ) and `max-height` property default value is none.

`min-height` say to the browser: hey guy! you must start height from my value.

I hope it is useful for you!

Comment: FYI for future visitors, this is a reply to the [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296182/do-animations-stop-css-changes-after-animation-completion#comments-57296592) of the accepted answer.